# How do I solve the first phase (corners) of the gear cube when only one corner is out of place?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I learnt that there are three phases involved in solving a gear cube, the first being the corners. In EVERY video I watched, when they get two of a layer's corners to match, the other two are automatically paired, and they just have to do a few rotations to get those corners on one side. This doesn't happen to me. I know how to pair two corners, but when I look for the other two, they are most of the time apart. I can get one of those two to join the pair, but I don't know what to do with that last corner out of place.

In short, when I try solving the first phase, I can get three corners exactly where they should be, but I don't know how to get all four corners together.

[image: Three corners of yellow are aligned correctly. The other corner is in the opposite side]

[image: Three corners of purple are aligned correctly.]

Comment: Is this a normal Gear Cube or a Gear Cube Extreme? If a normal one, then it has been seriously abused cause this should not be possible. On a Gear Cube Extreme the middle layer has edges without gears, and then this is possible.

Comment: As @JaapScherphuis mentioned, you've probably skipped some gears while turning. If a Gear Cube is too loose, or if you scramble it too wild, gear could skip creating states that shouldn't be possible. Similar to a single rotated corner on a 3x3x3 Cube, which sometimes happens for people who speedcube as well. Simply put those gears back flat and solve it with the tutorials you've found. And next time scramble it a bit more calmly. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input, guys. I learnt from my friend that the cube is, in fact, a Gear Cube Extreme. And much to my surprise, because it was a normal Gear Cube I ordered for. It has those edges without gears, like @JaapScherphuis mentioned. I've been watching and reading the wrong tutorials all along. I found one for the Gear Cube Extreme and I've been able to solve the corners, though it was quite difficult. Thanks again.